# Source for zeh le'umas zeh interpretation

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

There is a well known concept in Jewish thought that things manifest themselves equally in the realms of holiness and unholiness, kind of like a cosmic balance. Many mefarshim quote this pasuk from Koheles as hinting to that - zeh le'umas zeh asah elokim. Does anyone know the earliest source for this?

Comment: The Gemara Chagiga 15A mentions it https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.15a.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi